# How do I use an int& parameter with a default value?

Tags: c++

I have to add a default `int&` argument (Eg iNewArgument) to an existing function definition in a header file:

What is the syntax to initialize the last argument to make it take a default value?

```
..
virtual int ExecNew
    (int& param1, int& RowIn,int& RowOut, char* Msg = '0', 
            bool bDebug=true, int& iNewArgument = NULL ) = 0 ;
.
.
```

NULL is #defined to 0

> Error: default argument: cannot convert from `int` to `int&`

Comment: If you want it to be able to be null, then you need a pointer not a reference.

Comment: I'm with Mike on this. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190571/c-int-reference-question/3190603#3190603).

Comment: I take this back (and I deleted my answer). Except for Johannes everybody overlooked the `virtual`. It's not a good idea to have default arguments for `virtual` functions.

Comment: `char* Msg = '0'` should be either `char* Msg = NULL` or `char* Msg = "0"`, depending on your intent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example indicates that you are creating a virtual function. Default arguments in virtual (especially pure) functions are not a good idea, because they are not considered when you call an overridden function.

```
struct A {
  virtual void f(int = 4711) = 0;
};

struct B : A {
  virtual void f(int) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Now, if someone calls `f` on a `B` object, he will *have* to provide the argument - the default isn't used. You would have to duplicate the default argument in the derived class, which creates ugly redundancies. Instead, you can use the non-virtual interface pattern

```
struct A {
  void f(int a) {
    int out;
    f(a, out);
  }

  void f(int a, int &out) {
    doF(a, out);
  }

protected:
  virtual void doF(int a, int out&) = 0;
};
```

The user can now call `f` with one, and with two arguments, from whatever class type he calls the function, and the implementers of `A` don't have to worry about the default argument. By using overloading instead of default arguments, you don't need to break your head around lvalues or temporaries.

Comment: Oh, everybody overlooked this! Good catch, Johannes, `+1` from me. (And, BTW, it is even more severe if `B::f()` has a different default argument - the code silently compiles, but has different semantics!

Answer (score 4):

The only meaningful way to supply a default argument to a non-const reference is to declare a standalone object with static storage duration and use it as a default argument

```
int dummy = 0;

...
virtual int ExecNew(/* whatever */, int& iNewArgument = dummy) = 0;
```

Whether it will work for you or not is for you to decide.

Inside the function, if you'll need to detect whether the default argument was used, you may use address comparison

```
if (&iNewArgument == &dummy)
  /* Default argument was used */
```

Comment: If inside the function you're comparing addresses, then this is an indication that the function should take this object per reference. If addresses are important for the function's semantic, this should be visible to the caller.

Comment: @sbi: In this particular case the address is taken as an implementation detail with no interface meaning. It would be incorrect to expose that implementation detail to the user. However, I'd just add that in best case the default argument should be chosen so that (an the function is designed so that) the function does not need to detect the fact that the default argument has been used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  The INewArgument must either be a raw int or a const reference.  A non-const reference cannot be used the way you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In short you're going to have to rework you problem.  You can either make your int& a regular int and lose the reference behavior (being able to pass out the changed value) or give up having a default value.

Comment: Looking at your example code again, what you are trying to do with INewArgument is pass a pointer, not a reference.  That's your other option in this case: pass a pointer rather than a reference.  It works well if you don't mind mucking with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The default has to be lvalue for a non-const reference type, so what try to do above won't work. What you can do is:

```
namespace detail {
  int global;
}

void foo(int &x = detail::global) {}
```

or

```
void bar(const int &x = int(3)) {}
```

Comment: For your first case: `NULL` as "I have no parameter for you" is universally understood, `detail::global` not. And for the second case: built-ins should be taken per copy, not per `const` reference.

Comment: The second variant is still useful for more complex data types, e.g. void foo(const std::set<int> &x = std::set<int>()), which sometimes makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You say NULL is `#defined` to 0, so it's a literal value. The parameter is a reference to an int, which means the function would be able to change the value. How do you change the value of a literal?

You need to make it a `const` reference, or don't make it a reference at all.